# How to create a dynamic table in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a dynamic table in jQuery. But my code creates a table for each of  my element.

```
var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
var str = dataItem.Description;
var spl = str.split(','), part;
var spl2 = "";
for (var i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
    part = spl[i].split(':');
    content = "<table>" + "<tr><td>" + part[0] + "</td>" + "<td>" + part[1] + "</td></tr>";
    spl2 += content;
}
content += "</table>"
var desc = "<div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'>" + "<span>" +
    spl2
    + "</span><br/>" +
    +  "</div>";
```

Which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: its because you are creating your table tag inside the for loop. put the  `<table>' tag before the loop like you are closing the table tag

Comment: @AnoopLL                                                                                                I tried this code before,but my code is like this `<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>{"Id"</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>{"Id"</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>"FirstName"</td>
<td>null</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>`

Comment: you got the solution?

Comment: @AnoopLL No.I have 13 parameters.first this code creates a table with the firs parameter,second time it creates  a table with my first parameter+second parameter.at the end I have 13 table that my 13 table contains all the parameter

Comment: @balouchi..just write spl2 = content; instead of spl2 += content; in for loop. as i mentioned below in answer. it will solve your problem

Comment: @DharaParmar Thank U for your answer.I have another question "how can add class to this table?"

Comment: just write:      content ="<table class='testcls'>" before for loop starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you were adding table in for loop, so it was creating table for each item.Try this:

```
var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
var str = dataItem.Description;
var spl = str.split(','), part;
var spl2 = "";
content ="<table>"
 for (var i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
     part = spl[i].split(':');
     content += "<tr><td>" + part[0] + "</td>" + "<td>" + part[1] + "</td></tr>";
     spl2 = content;
 }
content += "</table>"

// you can also assign spl2 = content; over here.
    var desc = "<div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'>" + "<span>" +
        spl2
        + "</span><br/>" +
        +  "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
var str = dataItem.Description;
var spl = str.split(','), part;
var spl2 = "";
var content = "<table>";
 for (var i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
     part = spl[i].split(':');
     content += "<tr><td>" + part[0] + "</td>" + "<td>" + part[1] + "</td></tr>";
     spl2 += content;
 }
content += "</table>"
var desc = "<div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'>" + "<span>" +
    spl2
    + "</span><br/>" +
    +  "</div>";
```

Updated your script

Comment: check it as the <table> tag is outside the for loop this should not happen ,can you check again with the above code